# c++ code doesn't stop running, "Address boundary error"

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this code, and when running it won't stop. if I comment `*dest = source;` it does end. I think it has something to do with pointing to a place that doesn't exist, bc when I run the file with the terminal and not vscode, it goes: `terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)`

my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

uint16_t codeseg[359];  
uint16_t stack[9]; // the stack (מחסנית)
uint16_t dataseg[9999]; // data segment
uint16_t ax = 0, bx = 0, cx = 0, dx = 0, cp = 0, sp = 9; // registers.
uint16_t* regs[] = {&ax, &bx, &cx, &dx, &cp, &sp}; // for when processing machine code.
uint16_t val1, val2; // for instructions.
uint16_t* dest; // destenation & source - for instructions.
uint16_t source;
int ret;

int destSource(){
    // find the destenation and source for comamnd like mov, mul, add, sub
    val1 = codeseg[cp + 1];
    val2 = codeseg[cp + 2];

    if (val1 & 0xC000 == 0xC000){
        // register
        dest = regs[val1 - 0xC000];
    } else if (val1 & 0x4000 == 0x4000){ 
        // adress
        dest = regs[val1 - 0x4000];
    } else if (val1 & 0x8000 == 0x8000) {
        // numeric value
        printf("cp: %d | destenation must be register / adress", cp);
        return 1;
    }

    if (val2 & 0xC000 == 0xC000){
        // register
        source = *regs[val2 - 0xC000];
    } else if (val2 & 0x4000 == 0x4000){ 
        // adress
        source = *regs[val2 - 0x4000];
    } else if (val2 & 0x8000 == 0x8000) {
        // numeric value
        source = val2 - 0x8000;
    }

    return 0;
}


int main() {

    // for testing
    codeseg[0] = 1;
    codeseg[1] = 0xC000;
    codeseg[2] = 0xC000 + 1;
    bx = 1;

    for (;cp < 360; cp += 3){

        switch(codeseg[cp]){
            case 1: // mov
                ret = destSource();
                if (ret == 1) return 1;
                *dest = source;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A bug from the future: on your last iteration, `cp` is 357, and then you are going to access `cp+2`, which is out of bounds. (359, 9, and 9999 are very odd array sizes.)

Answer (score 0):

`for (;cp < 360; cp += 3)` is trying to loop 120 times, but you only have 1 set of 3 codeseg values, so on the 2nd iteration it is accessing values that are not there.

So in that case - dest is probally being set to abd unknown place - and then `*dest =` is going to attempt to write to that unknown place.

Comment: I've tried (;cp < 3; cp += 3) for testing but that didn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

In the first run, codeseg contains :

```
[0]:1
[1]:49152
[2]:49153
[3...n]: 0
```

Therefore `val1 = 49152` and `val2 = 49153` in the beggining of the `destSource` function. Following the logic, you can see that `val2 & 0xC000` is indeed equal to `0xC000` so the only condition that applies, sets `source` to `*regs[val2 - 0xC000]` which is `1`. See, dst is still `0x0000000000000000` since it has not been modified at all. And then trying to write on it will segfault.

Comment: > See, dst is still 0x0000000000000000 since it has not been modified at all. And then trying to write on it will segfault.
wdym? what's dst?